# How to access data from a row_type variable if we know the column name in runtime in Oracle plsql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In the below code, I am passing the column name to function func_conv() and inside the function, I want to access r1 along with the column name to get the column value from r1. However, it does not allow me to do so. So I tried to use dynamic SQL to solve this problem inside function but, I could not achieve it through dynamic SQL as well.

```
    declare 
      CURSOR c IS
      SELECT * FROM table1;
    r1 c%ROWTYPE;
    
    function func_conv(col_name varchar2) returns number is 
    begin
      if r1.col_name is null then return 1 else return 0;
    end;

   begin
     for s in (SELECT * from table1) LOOP
      r1 := s;
      dbms_output.put_line(func_conv('record_date'));
     end loop;
   end;
```

Comment: Oracle objects (tables, views, records, object types) have no dynamic access to their properties without dynamic SQL or PL/SQL. PL/SQL requires compilation, so all the names should be valid.

Comment: You may implement object type and corresponding `get` method, but object type will also be static. Or you may use `sys_refcursor` and open it for dynamic SQL, but in the end you will not be able to dynamically access it and should provide static type as a target for `fetch` (or process cursor at the app side)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mechanism to do it via dynamic PLSQL, that will work from 18c onwards - it must be a table rowtype not a cursor rowtype. But I'd advise against such an approach because a better option would be to factor a nullness check into the SQL itself rather than doing it for each row fetched.  That's a LOT of dynamic SQL calls which will be a performance killer.

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2      r1 emp%rowtype;
  3
  4      function func_conv(col_name varchar2,therow emp%rowtype) return number is
  5        outval number;
  6      begin
  7          execute immediate '
  8          declare
  9            r emp%rowtype := :inval;
 10          begin
 11            :outval := case when r.'||col_name||' is null then 1 else 0 end;
 12          end;' using in therow, out outval ;
 13
 14       return outval;
 15
 16      end;
 17
 18  begin
 19       for s in (SELECT * from scott.emp) LOOP
 20        r1 := s;
 21        dbms_output.put_line(func_conv('ename',r1));
 22       end loop;
 23     end;
 24  /
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2      r1 emp%rowtype;
  3
  4      function func_conv(col_name varchar2,therow emp%rowtype) return number is
  5        outval number;
  6      begin
  7          execute immediate '
  8          declare
  9            r emp%rowtype := :inval;
 10          begin
 11            :outval := case when r.'||col_name||' is null then 1 else 0 end;
 12          end;' using in therow, out outval ;
 13
 14       return outval;
 15
 16      end;
 17
 18  begin
 19       for s in (SELECT * from scott.emp) LOOP
 20        r1 := s;
 21        dbms_output.put_line(func_conv('comm',r1));
 22       end loop;
 23     end;
 24  /
1
0
0
1
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Yes, it's a serious performance hit. My goal is to read the table once run certain validation functions, for several columns of that table.  Also, columns on which functions will run can not be known during compile time. So my initial intention was to read the same table multiple times for each validation as below. table1 is being read multiple time.

Validation_type1(col1,filter_clause)
{
  select ....
  from table1
  where filter_clause
}

Validation_type2(col2,filter_clause) 
{
  select ....
  from table1
  where filter_clause
}

Comment: The more you put in SQL (and less in PLSQL) the better you'll generally be for performance.  As such, you might look at dynamically generating the entire SQL, ie, use all_tab_cols to generate a SQL that does:  "select validation(col1,...), validation(col3, ...) etc etc from table" and then fetch from that